# Why does boost::spirit::qi::parse() not set this boost::variant's value?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-variant

<strike>When trying to parse text into a boost::variant, the variant's value does not get changed.
The parsers by themselves appear to work fine, so my assumption is that I'm doing something wrong with the variant code.</strike>

I'm using boost 1.46.1 and <strike>the following code compiles in</strike> Visual Studio 2008.

#### 1st Update

hkaiser noted that the rule and grammar template arguments must not be `Variant` but `Variant()`.
This got a bit "further" as I now have a compilation error in `boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1304)`. The comment says:

```
// NOTE TO USER :
// Compile error here indicates that the given type is not 
// unambiguously convertible to one of the variant's types
// (or that no conversion exists).
```

So apparently the attribute of the expression `(qi::double_ | +qi::char_)` is not `boost::variant<double, std::string>`. But what is it then?

#### 2nd Update

Using `typedef boost::variant<double, std::vector<char>> Variant;` works for the parser. However, this is not as easy to use as std::string...

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    typedef std::string::const_iterator Iterator;

    const std::string a("foo"), b("0.5");

    // This works
    {
        std::string stringResult;
        Iterator itA = a.begin();
        const bool isStringParsed =
            qi::parse(itA, a.end(), +qi::char_, stringResult);

        double doubleResult = -1;
        Iterator itB = b.begin();
        const bool isDoubleParsed =
            qi::parse(itB, b.end(), qi::double_, doubleResult);

        std::cout
                << "A Parsed? " << isStringParsed <<
                ", Value? " << stringResult << "\n"
                << "B Parsed? " << isDoubleParsed <<
                ", Value? " << doubleResult << std::endl;

        // Output:
        // A Parsed? 1, Value? foo
        // B Parsed? 1, Value? 0.5
    }


    // This also works now
    {
        typedef boost::variant<double, std::vector<char>> Variant; // vector<char>, not string!

        struct variant_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Variant()> // "Variant()", not "Variant"!
        {
            qi::rule<Iterator, Variant()> m_rule; // "Variant()", not "Variant"!

            variant_grammar() : variant_grammar::base_type(m_rule)
            {
                m_rule %= (qi::double_ | +qi::char_);
            }
        };

        variant_grammar varGrammar;

        Variant varA(-1), varB(-1);
        Iterator itA = a.begin();
        const bool isVarAParsed = qi::parse(itA, a.end(), varGrammar, varA);
        Iterator itB = b.begin();
        const bool isVarBParsed = qi::parse(itB, b.end(), varGrammar, varB);

        // std::vector<char> cannot be put into std::cout but
        // needs to be converted to a std::string (or char*) first.
        // The conversion I came up with is very ugly but it's not the point
        // of this question anyway, so I omitted it.
        // You'll have to believe me here, when I'm saying it works..

        // Output:
        // A (variant): Parsed? 1, Value? foo, Remaining text = ''
        // B (variant): Parsed? 1, Value? 0.5, Remaining text = ''
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule's attribute must be specified using the function declaration syntax:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, Variant()> m_rule;
```

I have not tried, but I believe it will work after this change (the same is required for the grammar, btw).

Comment: Thanks! I missed that. However, now it's not compiling anymore. I updated the question.

Comment: @hkaiser: isn't it time for a FAQ entry on this one. Perhaps it already exists, but it comes up often enoug...

Comment: @sehe Apparently there is a FAQ entry for this (http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/doc-addendum/faq/#attributes). But maybe it should say "Why does my code not work when I use variants?" or something like that.

Comment: @foraidt: sadly this has _nothing_ to do with Variant, it applies to all attribute typed. Perhaps you were looking for the FQA with your name on it :)

Comment: This has been updated in the new (upcoming) version of Spirit (Boost V1.47). There using variant<double, std::string> should work.